# If statement in OnTriggerEnter function is not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

I can't understand this phenomenon now.

According to the c# code, count is added first, and the number of count is checked and the if statement is entered. (The reason that else is not used is that 1 and limitcount can be the same.) However, when actually executed, it is confirmed that count is 1 in the first trigger, but it does not enter the if statement. The second trigger returns 1 again, and after running Debug.log, the count is incremented to 2. What the problem is this?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.GetComponentInParent<NHWTractor>() != null) { 
        if (other.GetComponentInParent<NHWTractor>().PV.IsMine)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            Debug.Log(count.ToString());
            if (count == 1)
            {
                fstRedCheck = redSign.activeSelf;
                Debug.Log("first Check : "+ fstRedCheck.ToString());
            }
            if (count == limitCount)
            {
                scRedCheck = redSign.activeSelf;
                Debug.Log("Light Check : " + scRedCheck.ToString());
                if (fstRedCheck || scRedCheck)
                    other.GetComponentInParent<NHWTractor>().TrafficEvent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[firstTrigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqOwA.jpg)

[secondTrigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1ykw.jpg)

[triggerSetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz6E1.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried debbuging with breakpoints?

Comment: what is 'count' and 'limitCount' values on the start? do you handle them in other places?

Comment: Debugging currently not running due to Unity PhotonView issue. Debugging doesn't work, but the source runs fine. I reinstalled the package a few times, but after a few days it breaks again, so I leave it alone. limitCount is the number of triggers to check for signal violations. When unprotected left turn is possible, there are 2 triggers, and when not possible, only 1 is used.

Comment: if the code runs try to debug it with debug.log messages and tell us there it stopes working

Comment: Please check the photos. I am using the debug log.